# SQlite define column based on closest difference from two tables (vlookup)

Tags: sqlite, join, where-clause, min, vlookup

I have two tables {example data - Table A has several hundred rows and Table B has several thousand rows}.  I'd like to populate column B2 with the smallest absolute difference between column B1 and column A2 - that corresponds to column A1.  ...OR... set B2 = A1 where abs(B1-A2) closest to zero.

So in my table below the first row B1 - A2 = 1.6 - 1.4 = 0.2, which is the smallest difference and corresponds to 0 in A1 (and 1 and 2 for the next two rows, although that coincidence is born out of my lack of creativity not the actual table structure).

**Table A**

```
A1         A2
0         1.4
1         2.6
2         4.3
```

**Table B**

```
B1         B2
1.6        []
2.7        []
4.4        []
```

Or B2 = A1 where abs(B1-A2) closest to zero.  I'm at a loss on how to define this using SQLite.  I've searched through SO but haven't found this question phrased close enough for my meager SQLite skills to make the jump.  Closest I've seen is [SQLite - getting closest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739759/sqlite-getting-closest-value) but this is one table and only a select not an update.

I know most would prefer I provide an answer as a starting point, but they either fail completely or give me an error about trying to use an aggregate function (min) so I don't think it will help with the question (but if you are curious I've sadly spent 2 hours on this).  So I resolve down to this: is there a way for SQLite to perform this?  Any help is much appreciated!

B2 = A1 where abs(B1-A2) closest to zero.  In effect this is a SQLite vlookup (Excel) style question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed B1 value called `X`, this query would compute the difference for each A record:

```
SELECT *,
       abs(X - A2)
FROM A
```

To get the smallest value, we could use MIN, but that would only compute the difference itself.
To get other values from the same record, it is better to use ORDER BY, like this, so that the first record returned is the one with the smallest difference:

```
SELECT A1,
       A2,
       abs(X - A2)
FROM A
ORDER BY 3
```

With a LIMIT, only the first record is returned:

```
SELECT A1,
       A2,
       abs(X - A2)
FROM A
ORDER BY 3
LIMIT 1
```

Now we want only the `A1` value, so we wrap another query around this:

```
SELECT A1
FROM (SELECT A1,
             abs(X - A2)
      FROM A
      ORDER BY 2
      LIMIT 1)
```

Now we can use this entire query as a correlated subquery for the UPDATE, where `X` is now the `B1` value from the current record:

```
UPDATE B
SET B2 = (SELECT A1
          FROM (SELECT A1,
                       abs(B1 - A2)
                FROM A
                ORDER BY 2
                LIMIT 1))
```