# How can i predict the closest value according to my search?

Tags: android

```
8906002660551
8904011505795
8906007240123
8901207503139
8904011516272
8904025968265
8906002411344
8906002412549
8906002411146
8901499009272
8904011516166
8904011504156
8901691011318
.
.
.
.
```

There are like 1000's of numbers like these in my sqlite db. When I search for a number like 8906007240125 i need to predict the closest value i.e 8906007240123. How can I do that?

I'll be glad if anyone come's up with implementation code. Because I'm failing in it big time. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739759/sqlite-getting-closest-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

use this query and post `num` while calling json parser

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name ORDER BY ABS(? - num) LIMIT 1
```

`?` represents the value you want to compare against.

Comment: How does a json parser come into this?

Comment: he is calling from android so to call a .php file in his server he should use json parser

Comment: but he could as well communicate via XML and use some other technology as PHP at the server ... Or not use a server at all (note that sqlite is mentioned in the question) You made a lot of unwarranted assumptions.